# What's the difference between 'any more' and 'anymore'?

Tags: grammar

In the phrase *Can't afford to spend any more time*, I am not sure if I need a space between *any* and *more*.

I have checked two sources including [the Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any-more-or-anymore) and [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/anymore-vs-any-more/). They suggest the following:

> **Any more is A determiner**
>   It is similar to *some more* and describes an indefinite quantity of something.

> Example:
>   Would you like any more tea?

**Anymore =  adverb**
It means 'no longer' or 'in the past, but not now'

> Example:
>   The cost of electricity is not cheap anymore.

So, in the phrase, *Can't afford to spend any more time*, which would you use?

There is an indefinite quantity of time, so based on the examples above it would be '*any more*'. But then, the phrase also implies that they had time in the past but no longer, so does that mean it would be '*anymore*'?

Also, does it make a difference if you are using American or British English, as the Cambridge link kind of suggests that *anymore* applies more to American English?

Comment: When "any more" is used in a noun phrase, as in _any more time_, it is a DP (determinative phrase) where "any" modifies "more", and they are treated as two separate words. The adverb "any more" found in _I don't want to go there any more_, is written as two words in BrE but one ("anymore") in AmE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding which is correct has less to do with indefiniteness and more to do with what each of the parts of speech are.

> Can't afford to spend any more time

is the correct construction. Here, you have an **adverb** *any* modifying an **adjective** *more*, which itself modifies a **noun** *time*.

Comment: Would it be different for British English vs American English?

Comment: I believe it would be the same for British English, yes.

Answer (score 4):

From [Any more or anymore?](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any-more-or-anymore) on the Cambridge Dictionary website...

> **Any more** as a determiner
>
> We use any more as a determiner to describe ‘an indefinite quantity of something’. Any more is similar to some more. Some more is more common in affirmative statements; any more is more common in questions, in clauses with if and in sentences with negative words such as hardly, never, scarcely:
>
> *Would you like any more tea?*

---

> **Any more** as an adverb
>
> Any more is also an adverb and has the meaning of ‘no longer’ or ‘in the past but not now.’ In this meaning, we use it in end position:
>
> *We don’t go to Cornwall on holiday any more.* (We used to go in the past but not now.)

## <sub>Especially in American English, any more, as an adverb, can be written as one word, anymore:</sub>

> *He doesn’t cycle anymore.*

---

Personally, I'd rarely if ever use the single-word form, just as I tend to stick with ***any time*** rather than ***anytime***. But I'm a Brit - and per the bolded text above, that's probably relevant.